# Mouse-over script for touch devices

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, mouseevent, jquery-events

I'm trying to use this image skimming script on my website, which I want to be iPhone and iPad compatible. The problem is it is based on mouse-over so it doesn't work on touch. Any way anyone could help me change the script so instead of hovering over the images you click and drag to skim through them? So it could work on touch devices? Thanks. (Example of the script: http://www.fourcornersbooks.co.uk )

```
(function($) {
$.fn.skim = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

        var container = $(this);
        var numImgs    = container.find("img").size();
        var zoneWidth  = container.width() / numImgs;

        container.find("img").css("display", "none");
        container.find("img:first").css("display", "block");

        container.mousemove(function(e) {
            var offset = container.offset();
            x = e.pageX - offset.left;
            var currentZone = Math.floor(x / zoneWidth);
            $(this).find("img").css("display", "none");
            $(this).find("img:eq(" + currentZone + ")").css("display", "block");
        });
        container.mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find("img").css("display", "none");
            $(this).find("img:first").css("display", "block");
        });

    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This one works for example: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-360-view-image-slider-javascript but all of these rotation viewers run in loop and I need a fixed image on each side (start and end image) so you skim between them

Comment: just use jquery Punch- it converts single clicks into hover and click again for normal click

Comment: What do you want? If you would use click, then it would work when you touch, but what would you expect to happen when I touch it instead of mousein, mouseout?

Comment: I really don't know javascript well enough, sadly. I'm just looking for a script that would let me touch (or click) and move through the images, instead of hovering over them